# postgresql could not connect error.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, psql

Here is my error.

```
PG::Error - could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I installed postgresql using homebrew into /usr/local/bin/psql
In order to get it to recognize this version I had to add this to my bash file.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
```

When I cd into my rails app and run command

```
rails s
```

it starts up with the following

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.0.0.beta1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Then when I try to view the app on `http://0.0.0.0:3000` I get the above error 
anyone might know why this might happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message says, the most likely cause of this error is that you are not actually running the postgres server. Normally you'd boot this up with */etc/init.d/pg_ctl,* but since you installed this through brew, just run the following command in a Terminal window

```
postgres
```

And the server should boot up. If you don't have this set to automatically start upon launch you'll need to run that command every time after you restart your machine.

Comment: postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.

Comment: Ok found how to start it using command line 'brew info postgres'. the startup line is '    pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start'

Comment: Had this error on Nitrous.io when I changed from mysql to postgres.  Had to restart the box and change my database.yml to have `host: localhost` and change `listen address to '*'`.
My final solution was found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/461257/cant-connect-to-postgres-in-production/461265#461265)